# stats models giving weird results. R squared value is wrong

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I am using the statsmodels package to run a simple OLS regression on a big data set(2m+ observations). 
My regression command is:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm   
import pandas as pd 
patent = pd.read_csv('input.csv')  

#Input.csv contains the columns mentioned in the regression equation
result = sm.ols(formula="generality~C(id)+C(year)+C(appyear)+familiarity + je",data = patent).fit()
```

When I try to print the summary of the above regression I get this:

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py:1036: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
   return self.params / self.bse
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
   return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
   return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:1818: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
   cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)
                             OLS Regression Results                            
 ==============================================================================
 Dep. Variable:             generality   R-squared:                  -23041.069
 Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:             -23041.886
 Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                -2.820e+04
 Date:                Mon, 30 Oct 2017   Prob (F-statistic):               1.00
 Time:                        20:39:45   Log-Likelihood:            -8.9192e+06
 No. Observations:             1720455   AIC:                         1.784e+07
 Df Residuals:                 1720393   BIC:                         1.784e+07
 Df Model:                          61                                         
 Covariance Type:            nonrobust
```

Clearly, the R squared value is wrong. Am I doing something incorrect in the regression command?

*Note: The data is too big for me to paste here. There are roughly 40 categories in year and appyear respectively.*

Comment: My main guess would be that it doesn't use float64. Check `result.model.exog.dtype` to see what the dtype of the underlying data is.

Comment: Also, does the parameter table, i.e. the second part of summary(), contain nans or infs?

Comment: It is float64.. Also, there are no NaNs or Infs. I cleaned them up before creating the csv file

Comment: What are result.ssr and result.centered_tss, which are used to compute rsquared? Also do you get a warning about condition number or small eigenvalues at the end of summary? (There is a numerical problem with the dataset, but that's difficult to identify without much information.)

Comment: There are collinear variables because I use a lot of factor variables, some of them are bound to be collinear.  Is there a way to omit collinear variables while running the fit model?

Comment: There is currently no built-in way in statsmodels to remove collinear variables, and pinv might have a rcond that is too low in this case to regularize sufficiently.